# Compare different versions of docker

Tags: docker

I'd like to determine the age of a docker installation on Cent OS 6.9 which is `Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1`. My other system with Arch shows `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658bed64`.

How do these versions compare? I could not find a list or something that would show different docker version schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker went from 1.xx directly to 17.yy. You can see it on this picture:

[image: taken from https://docs.docker.com/]

It had some massive engine changes between [see here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/migration/), and on version 17.06 it completely built on [Moby Project](http://mobyproject.org/).

Comment: I guess the centos docker version is ancient then... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: CentOS 6.x is capped at Docker 1.7.1 (which is before they moved to the `{YY}.{MM}.{patch}` versioning.

Anything newer from the CentOS/RHEL/Amazon/Oracle family requires 7.x or newer.